# Are There Catchy Names for Wallpaper Groups?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, geometric-topology

To supplement the IUC's drab naming system for [frieze groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frieze_group), John Conway invented his own catchy footstep naming system. Groups like P1M1 and P11G became "Sidle" and "Step". He and Bill Thurston also invented [orbifold notation](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.uwm.edu/dist/0/158/files/2017/04/Conway.Orbifold-Notation-for-Surface-Groups.1990-2d6oy2f.pdf) to describe wallpaper groups - the two dimensional analog of frieze groups. Still, their naming convention does more to put wallpaper groups in a topological context than to expand accessibility. Are there any other wallpaper group notations that are less precise but perhaps more 'catchy'?

Comment: Since wallpaper groups are  [*crystallographic groups in the plane*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146824/proof-that-there-exist-only-17-wallpaper-groups-tilings-of-the-plane), there might be more notations in crystallography?

Comment: There are catchy names on page 440 of that that paper you linked.