# Subgroups of crystallographic groups

Tags: group-theory, crystallography

I am trying to understand the structure of crystallographic groups and came to the following question. Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two non-isomorphic crystallographic groups of the same dimension and the same point groups. Can $G_1$ contain a subgroup isomorphic to $G_2$? In other words, can $G_2$ be a subgroup of $G_1$?

I tried to play with 1-cocycles, but I don't see how a 1-cocycle could change when we pass to a subgroup. Also I tried to conjugate one group inside another group -- came to nothing.

Comment: So we have extensions $1\rightarrow \Bbb Z^n\rightarrow G_i\rightarrow F_i\rightarrow 1$ for $i=1,2$, and $F_1\cong F_2$, $G_2\le G_1$ but $G_1\not\cong G_2$?

Comment: Yes, is it possible?  #Comments must be at least ...

Comment: I have found the answer. It is possible even in dimension 2.

Comment: Which of the $17$ groups did you take for $G_1$ and $G_2$ in dimension $2$? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3146824/proof-that-there-exist-only-17-wallpaper-groups-tilings-of-the-plane) for a reference with extensions.

Comment: The group p1m1 (No. 3) contains as a subgroup the group p1g1 (No. 4), while both groups have $C_2$ at their point groups.

Comment: I see. The notes by [Morandi](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj67_Pfx6b9AhXAgf0HHSIYAlEQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.nmsu.edu%2F~pamorand%2FNotes%2FWallpaper.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1rQ70aPU1nHMOA-N2muZoH) have some details using cohomology, also for p1m1 and p1g1 (the point group is $D_{1,p}\cong C_2$), with cocycles. Perhaps it is interesting for you.